# Segmentation Fault when receiving string message

Tags: c, string, sockets

I am sending a string message from a server implemented in C to a client.In order to do this, I first send the message's length, and then the actual message. The following is a code snippet from my server.

```
int length = strlen(message);
send(serversock, &length, sizeof (int), 0);
send(serversock, message, sizeof (char) * length, 0);
```

The following is my client's code:

```
int length;
recv(clientsock, &length, sizeof (int), 0);

printf("size: %d\n", length);

char* message;
recv(clientsock, message, sizeof (char) * length, 0);
printf("Got Message %s\n", message); // I get Segmentation Fault here
```

When I receive a message, I try printing it out. However, I get a segmentation fault. Can anyone help me please?

PS: I do manage to get the length value

Comment: The problem is that you are attempting socket programming, a fairly advanced topic, without grasping the fundamental concepts of arrays and pointers first.

Comment: To be fair, judging whether a topic is too advanced for you, requires figuring out what required knowledge you lack. Knowing what you don't know, without trying and failing (or being told) isn't trivial.

Comment: @Useless Well, if you read a C programming book, there is a reason you don't find socket programming in chapter one. You will however find arrays and pointers somewhere around chapter 4-5 or so. If you haven't encountered sockets before then, that's a sound hint of them being more advanced than the topics you have already read and grasped so far. Assuming of course, that you read books from left to right.

Answer (score 2):

```
char* message;
recv(clientsock, message, sizeof (char) * length, 0);
```

You need to allocate memory for `message` to point to. Here you are passing the uninitialized value of `message` pointer. Use `malloc` to allocate an array. Assuming `message` is a string:

```
char *message = malloc(length + 1);
```

Comment: How... many... times...? I've fed up with this!

Comment: @H2CO3 Indeed, at least ten questions like this each day. I can't even be bothered to find a duplicate. Going to vote for "too localized" for all these pointer bugs unless someone can point out a good faq post.

Comment: @Lundin Me too, and flagged as "very low quality" since no research effort is shown whatsoever.

Comment: @H2CO3 - please can you cut back on these types of comments. If you're not happy about something then downvote or flag. Filling the comments with this kind of stuff is not constructive or helping anyone.

Answer (score 1):

`recv` doesn't allocate memory, you need to do that explicitly:

```
int length;
recv(clientsock, &length, sizeof (int), 0);

printf("size: %d\n", length);

char* message = malloc(length+1); /* read into here */
recv(clientsock, message, sizeof (char) * length, 0);
message[length] = '\0'; /* nul terminated for printing */
printf("Got Message %s\n", message);
free(message); /* and remember you own this buffer */
```

When you read the length, you're reading into a variable that already exists: `int length;` reserves space for an integer.

When you read the message though, you used an uninitialized pointer, so it tried writing the message into some random location (hence the crash): `char *message;` only reserves space for a *pointer*.

Note that with a recent C compiler, you could use

```
char message[length+1];
```

instead. This way you don't need to explicitly `free` the array, but if `length` is too large you don't have any opportunity to handle the failure gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

Well, how does

```
send(serversock, &size, sizeof (int), 0);
```

represent sending the message's size?

In the client code, length is never initialized, and you have not allocated any memory for "message".  Are you showing all the code invovled.  If so, then your non-allocated char* message will certainly overwrite some random memory location after the call to recv.

Comment: sorry, changed size to length when writing the question to be more explanatory. length = size